# How to get Key Code for @ in Gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I'm unable to match the key code for @ in my code. I want to match @ in keydownhandler. I have taken shift + 2 = @ = 64

```
itemBox.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((int)event.getNativeKeyCode() == 64 )
            {
                System.out.println("eggheads");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i m also face the problem in it, in this i m unable to get the code for combined keys such as shift+2=@=64
but return 16 when we press shift and then 50 when 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it thanx 2 all

```
inputBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
                public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(event.getUnicodeCharCode());

            if(event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 64){
            item.add(box);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyPressed` event

```
itemBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyChar() == '@' )
                            {}
            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like you **must** use a `keypress`. On a French keyboard, the `@` is at AltGr+0 (or Ctrl+Alt+0) and the `keydown` for the 0 has apparently no modifier at all (tested in Chrome, on Linux, at http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html)

Comment: neither KeyAdapter nor addkeyListener it is addkeyboardListener which is also deprecated